# Using auto vs const auto& to temporary keep result of method call

Tags: c++

Assuming I have

```
class Container {
  public:
    T getValue() const { return t; }
    const T& getCRef() const { return t; }
  private:
    const T t;
};

void f(const T& arg) { ... }
```

What is the preferred way to bind return value temporarily inside a function? E.g. what should I prefer and why?

```
void method(const Container& c) {
  auto t1 = c.getValue();
  auto t2 = c.getCRef();
  const auto& t3 = c.getValue();
  const auto& t4 = c.getCRef();

  // Notes from discussion:  
  // 1. Neither Container not object T changes during execution  
  // 2. I don't need to modify T, just passing it through  

  f(t1);
  f(t2);
  f(t3);
  f(t4);
}
```

My understanding is that:

- t1 will benefit from copy elision and will result in one copy construction
- t2 will result in one copy construction as well
- t3 still result in copy construction of returned temporary that is then bound by const reference
- t4 should be no copy

Is that correct? If so, should I prefer `const auto&` over `auto` for such cases all the time? Also, should I prefer `getCRef()` interface over `getValue()` when I can guarantee that reference lives as long as underlying object does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that correct?

Yes.

> If so, should I prefer const auto& over auto for such cases all the time?

It depends on what you intend to do.

If you want a copy, then use an object variable. If you want to refer to an object stored elsewhere, then use a reference variable.

> Also, should I prefer getCRef() interface over getValue() when I can guarantee that reference lives as long as underlying object does?

Same as above.

> my intention is to pass unmodified result of one method call to another

> let's assume that object doesn't change for the duration

If `T` is trivial, then prefer object to avoid unnecessary indirection. If `T` is non-trivial, then prefer reference to avoid copying. If you don't know whether `T` is trivial, then assume that it is not.

Comment: For local variable, my intention is to pass unmodified result of one method call to another, but not immediately, thus I need a way to bind return value for some time. The question is should I generally prefer `const auto&` over `auto` in such cases since it seems to be cheaper most of the time (trivial types aside). The reason I'm asking is that there seems to be suggestions that `const auto&` should not be used other than for functions args/return, so I wonder what is the current consensus on this.

Comment: @nyrl `pass unmodified result` Do you intend to pass the value that the member had when you got it from the object, or the value that the member has at the moment `f` is called? `what is the current consensus` I doubt you'll get enough answers to get a decent sampling to gauge whether there even is a consensus.

Comment: This is a good question in general, but let's assume that object doesn't change for the duration of `method()` - so copy is not strictly required.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that correct?

Yes.

> Also, should I prefer `getCRef()` interface over `getValue()` when I can guarantee that reference lives as long as underlying object does?

You cannot guaranty lifetime of reference of the sub-object. Both are under user control.

Built-in types and "small" trivial types can be returned by value.
For others, const reference seems better (avoid extra copy).
Mostly same rules as for passing arguments.

> should I prefer `const auto&` over `auto` for such cases all the time?

As noted, `const auto` might be used instead of simply `auto` to have similar constness.

`auto` ensures that the value won't be changed if internal of the container class change (or is destroyed). (but entity might also be invalid in such situation as iterator)

`const auto&` doesn't ensure that.

`auto` does copy all the times. So extra copy when reference is returned.
It ensures lifetime of temporary when value is returned.

`const auto&` doesn't copy all the times.
It extends lifetime of **temporary**, but that construct has some pitfall:

`const auto& c = std::string("hello")[0]; // dangling reference`

whereas the string is a temporary, we use method which return reference.

Both have their usage.

Answer (score 0):

> should I prefer const auto& over auto

The `const` keyword is used to tell the programmer (and get this checked by the compiler!) that the variable will not be modified inside the function. It's nice, especially when dealing with references, to have that guarantee written instead of just deducing it by code inspection. It's good to make sure the behaviour is the expected: you may not need to modify something, but that keyword will make sure you don't.

> why would you use `const auto t` instead of `const auto& t`? I can only think about two cases: trivial types, and where you don't have a guarantee that underlying object is constant and you have to hold a copy.

The difference between the two options is that in one you're using a reference to an object. That may be important with larger variables, but is not the case with the trivial ones. Take, for instance, an int. You gain nothign from passing a reference to an int instead of an int. It's not wrong to do it, though.

Comment: Let's assume that I would write `const auto t1` and `const auto t2` in my example. The reason I phrased it this way is that I usually see people write either `auto t = ...` or `const auto& t = ...`, but I'm yet to see `const auto t = ...`.

Comment: @nyrl: I see and use the three versions.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, I exaggerated. However, why would you use `const auto t` instead of `const auto& t`? I can only think about two cases: trivial types, and where you don't have a guarantee that underlying object is constant and you have to hold a copy.

Comment: @nyrl I dont think this answer answers your question completely, but the reason for `const` it explains quite well

Comment: @nyrl: What would you use if replacing `auto` by specific type? nothing new with `auto`.